# How to set up a network for home network

Tags: networking

I am trying to set up a home network. I have two laptops and a tower all running Ubuntu 14.01 and have been trying to link them together in a private network with no internet access. I can't figure out how to get them to find each other.

Comment: What are your devices you are using to connect? (i.e. routers?, wireless ad-hoc?, or something else?)

Comment: You mean that you cannot `ping` the other systems? Assuming you have a working LAN, you can either set up `NFS` with `AutoFS` for a Linux LAN or `Samba` for a Linux/Windows LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
sudo su
apt-get update
apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get install samba samba-common samba-common-bin smbclient system-config-samba
apt-get clean
system-config-samba
```

Click on Preferences on the menu bar to open Server Setting window. 
In the Server settings window, on  the basic tab, you can setup or rename the samba Workgroup and short Description for the workgroup.
Make sure that the name of samba Workgroup did not match any Workgroups or any Domains on your network.
Then on the Security tab you can setup the configuration for:
Authentication Mode:
Authentication Server:
Kerberos Realm:
Encrypt Passwords:
Guest Account:

For the Authentication Mode, you can setup your samba server to:
ADS - Samba server act as a domain member in Active Directory domain.
Domain - Samba server relies for primary or backup domain controller to passes the username and password.
Server - Samba server verify the username and password on another samba sever, if fail then the samba server use the User authentication mode.
Share - Samba sever only prompt for username and password when only user connect to specific share directory.
User - User authentication mode (default setting), the samba user must provide username and password on a per samba server basis
To enable user to access the files and printer share on the Samba Server you need to create user for Samba Server.  The step by step procedure below show how to add user to Samba Server using the graphical Samba Server Configuration tool,
To create samba user go to Preferences tab, then click on Samba Users to open the Samba Users window. 
On the Samba Users window, click Add User button to open the Create New Samba User window. 
Provide the necessary information for samba user on Create New Samba User window.
Unix Username: Click and choose the username from local Fedora Core system user, you can add user to the list by using 'adduser' command.
Windows Username:  Provide the windows username for the samba user; make note that the Windows Username will be map with the Unix Username when user log in to the samba server.  Note: You can use same username for both Unix Username: and Windows Username:.
Samba Password:  Provide the password for samba user in order enable them to login to samba server.  Note: The password don't have to match the local Fedora Core user password neither the password from local user on Windows system.
Confirm Samba Password:  Retype the password.
Then click OK button to proceed. 
The screenshot of list of Samba Users available on the system. Click OK button after done with the samba user creation.